# Can spawning a new MDI child cause the old child's objects to get garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, nullreferenceexception, mdi

I have a custom wrapper for the `SerialPort` class. Whenever I only have one instance of the MDI child, all is fine, but whenever I spawn another one, I get slapped with a null reference on the first form. Apparently, when I spawned the new MDI child, the old MDI child's `SerialPort` got garbage collected.

I'm not doing anything fancy on the parent form. I'm simply showing another form using:

```
PrinterForm pf = new PrinterForm();
pf.MdiParent = this;
pf.Show();
```

Here's the [Github gist of the serialport class](https://gist.github.com/pandalion98/2a0494b5289f767bb06ed74dadffb2c2) and the [Github gist of the child form](https://gist.github.com/pandalion98/d40c8a01d4182497f98c267f0a3efcfb)

I'm not quite sure how to ask this, but how do I resolve it? It's happening on line 526 on the child form.

Comment: Where is `timer1` declared and when it is activated (started, enabled)?

Comment: @IvanStoev I did not realize it before, but at the time `timer1` starts, `serial1` isn't instantiated yet. A simple nullity check fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out. It had nothing to do with MDI.